# creating procedure or function with this select

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to figure out what is best solution for this select that i have. I need to create function or procedure that return one value ODD from all these unions.

```
SELECT ODD FROM SOCCER_PREMATCH_ODDS SO WHERE SO.FIXID =:fixid and SO.TYPE = :type and SO.RES = :res 
UNION 
SELECT ODD FROM LIVE_ODDS LO WHERE LO.FIXID =:fixid and LO.TYPE =:type and LO.RES =:res 
UNION
SELECT ODD FROM PREMATCH_BASKETBALL_ODDS BO WHERE BO.FIXID =:fixid and BO.TYPE = :type and BO.RES = :res 
UNION 
SELECT ODD FROM LIVE_BASKETBALL_ODDS LBO WHERE LBO.FIXID =:fixid and LBO.TYPE =:type and LBO.RES =:res
UNION
SELECT ODD FROM PREMATCH_TENIS_ODDS TEO WHERE TEO.FIXID =:fixid and TEO.TYPE = :type and TEO.RES = :res 
UNION 
SELECT ODD FROM LIVE_TENNIS_ODDS LTEO WHERE LTEO.FIXID =:fixid and LTEO.TYPE =:type and LTEO.RES =:res
UNION
SELECT ODD FROM PREMATCH_HANDBALL_ODDS HEO WHERE HEO.FIXID =:fixid and HEO.TYPE = :type and HEO.RES = :res 
UNION 
SELECT ODD FROM LIVE_HANDBALL_ODDS LHEO WHERE LHEO.FIXID =:fixid and LHEO.TYPE =:type and LHEO.RES =:res
```

So if anyone knows please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by one value ODD? Do you want only one row out of the many possible?

Answer (score 0):

Which "one value ODD"? UNION will return distinct ODD values, but that doesn't have to be a single value. What do you plan to do with these, once you get them?

Anyway, here's one option:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test
  2     RETURN SYS.odcinumberlist
  3  IS
  4     retval   SYS.odcinumberlist;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT odd
  7       BULK COLLECT INTO retval
  8       FROM (SELECT 1 odd FROM DUAL
  9             UNION
 10             SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
 11             UNION
 12             SELECT 2 FROM DUAL);
 13
 14     RETURN retval;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from table(f_test);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2

SQL>
```

Comment: yes, it should return distinct, but if ODD is null in one of the tables it should return null.

Comment: got two errors ,  Error(5,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COLLECT" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; 
and Error(21,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RETURN"

Answer (score 0):

```
    create or replace FUNCTION checkOdds(p_fixid in varchar2,p_type in varchar2, p_res in varchar2)
    RETURN varchar2
 AS
     ODDS varchar2(200);
 BEGIN
  select Odd into ODDS 
  from(
     SELECT odd FROM SOCCER_PREMATCH_ODDS SO WHERE SO.FIXID =p_FIXID and SO.TYPE = p_TYPE and SO.RES = p_RES
             UNION
             SELECT odd FROM LIVE_ODDS LO WHERE LO.FIXID =p_FIXID and LO.TYPE =p_TYPE and LO.RES =p_RES
            UNION
            SELECT odd FROM PREMATCH_BASKETBALL_ODDS BO WHERE BO.FIXID =p_FIXID and BO.TYPE = p_TYPE and BO.RES = p_RES
            UNION
            SELECT odd FROM LIVE_BASKETBALL_ODDS LBO WHERE LBO.FIXID =p_FIXID and LBO.TYPE =p_TYPE and LBO.RES =p_RES
            UNION 
            SELECT odd FROM PREMATCH_TENIS_ODDS TEO WHERE TEO.FIXID =p_FIXID and TEO.TYPE = p_TYPE and TEO.RES = p_RES
            UNION 
            SELECT odd FROM LIVE_TENNIS_ODDS LTEO WHERE LTEO.FIXID =p_FIXID and LTEO.TYPE =p_TYPE and LTEO.RES =p_RES
            UNION 
            SELECT odd FROM PREMATCH_HANDBALL_ODDS HEO WHERE HEO.FIXID =p_FIXID and HEO.TYPE = p_TYPE and HEO.RES = p_RES
            UNION
            SELECT odd FROM LIVE_HANDBALL_ODDS LHEO WHERE LHEO.FIXID =p_FIXID and LHEO.TYPE =p_TYPE and LHEO.RES =p_RES);
            RETURN ODDS;
          END;
```

here is what have I done and i got it what i needed.